# how to add button on uitableviewCell and delete previous on next cell selection

Tags: iphone, uitableview

In my uitableview I want to add two buttons on cell, When user selects some particular cell. Now if user selects another cell then button should be deleted from the last selected cell and added to the new selected cell.

Answer (score 1):

1. Keep a reference to the button at class level.
2. When you want to move the button call `[self.myMovingbutton removeFromSuperview]` and then `[cell addSubview:self.myMovingButton]`.

Comment: thanks for you answer. will you please tell me that if I'm tapping on row 1 then button is adding but same button is also adding on next 8th row? this my code for adding button.

takeTest_button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
            [takeTest_button setTitle:@"Download" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [takeTest_button setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 35)];
          
         [[self.practice_table cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].contentView addSubview:takeTest_button];

Comment: That really depends on what you want to do. The above idea is sharing one button for all the cells. As I read your question, this is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Subclass `UITableViewCell` and add the `UIButton` as a property on the subclass. Use that property to store your button instance. When re-using the cell you can check the value of the property to see if you need to remove the old button before adding the new one.

Answer (score 0):

**.h**

```
NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath;
```

**.m**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    //  . . Some Code . . .
    if ( selectedIndexPath.row = indexPath.row &&  selectedIndexPath.section = indexPath.section ) {
        button1.hidden = NO;
        button2.hidden = NO;
    } else {
        button1.hidden = YES;
        button2.hidden = YES;
    }
    //  . . Some Code . . .
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    selectedIndexPath = indexPath;
    [tableView relaodData];
}
```